# Stored procedure why return statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

General procedure are no return value then stored procedure why return?

Comment: You are not making any sense at all.

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, stored procedure do not return any value. They run from its beginning to its end and, when no more statements to execute, they get back to the invoking code.

The use of a `RETURN` statement within a stored procedure is when you don't want to continue its processing. Example:

You have a stored procedure that receives 3 parameters and returns 2, a result and a status code (e.g. SUCCESS or FAIL). The procedure first checks that all the received parameters are present and within legal values and, if not present or illegal values are found, you don't want to proceed and simply **RETURN** to the invoking code with the applicable status code. You do this through the `RETURN` command.

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what is your problem. You mean why SP need a return statement?

1. Because in some case, we need process cross table operation and complex calculation. If we need a result we should return a result from SP.
2. In some aggregate calculation we need a final result, but the aggregate SQL is very complex. So we need use the SP instead of general SQL statement then return a result.

Comment: You are completely wrong!! Stored procedures do NOT return a value like a function, and the only way for them to give data back to the calling code is through OUTPUT parameters.

Comment: You actually answered a question that is vague from horrid spelling and less than clear requirements...why?